# Stack collection, Push vs addElement

Tags: java, stack

This is not a pressing question, I'm just curious.

What is the difference between using push() to add another object to a Stack and using addElement() to add an object?

I have found elsewhere that there is no difference between things like push() and add(), since add() is inherited from Collections, but I'm still curious to find out if there is anything I should know.

Also, do they both have a similar return type?

Comment: Read the javadocs...

Comment: By the way, I won't recommend using `Stack` class since it inherits from `Vector` which [you shouldn't use in applications](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1386275/1065197), instead use [`Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) which provides behavior of both Stack and Queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inherited `addElement` method returns a `boolean` indicating success.

The [`push` method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Stack.java#Stack.push%28java.lang.Object%29) ignores that returned `boolean`, calls `addElement`, and returns the item itself.  Source code from the link:

```
public E push(E item) {
    addElement(item);

    return item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`addElement` is part of `Vector`, which `Stack` inherits.

`push` is an actual `Stack` method.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by inheritance in java. `addElement()` is a method from the super class `Vector` extended by `Stack`.

You should see this (the inheritance tree in particular):
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html